# Clear search result after page change in react

Tags: reactjs, search

My Question is:
I have two pages let say Home and search page. So on the search page I have table data and search input field. When I search on search input field it displays filter search data from the entire list of data and if I change to Home page and return back to search page it shows me the previously search data instead of displaying the entire list of data.

so I want the search page to display the entire list of data after you change to Home page and come back to search page again. Please help me guys. Thank you in advance.

Comment: And without any code you show to us - all we can do is cheer you up and give you an advice to clean the state on SearchPage component mounts. Which state, how to clean, when to clean - who knows. It could be redux, it could be props, ContextProvider, it can vary on your react-router configuration, literally hundrerds of variations.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.